# NotesAndAttachments

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I just learned the NotesAndAttachments relatedList was renamed to CombinedAttachments.  I seem to also have lost the ability to only show "Notes" from the `<apex:relatedList />` tag.  Does anyone know how to access ONLY notes using the new verbiage?

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_attachments_related_list.htm

Comment: Any ideas?  I've tried about everything I can think of...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I filed a case to ask about this question. Salesforce Support noted that there is no way to only show Notes through that Visualforce tag.

You could alternatively rebuild the related list using a PageBlockTable and only query for Notes related to that object, but that does require custom development.

Comment: Yea, not the answer I was looking for, but was the expected answer... Disappointing, but thanks for following up...